# How to create JSON object in Google Apps Script by iterating a range

Tags: json, google-apps-script

I am trying to write a script to batch update products in a Woocommerce store via Rest API. API requires to send request as a JSON object, but I can't build the Object in the necessarily format.

Object should look like this:

```
'{
"update": [
    {
      "id": 799,
      "name": "product name"
    },
    {
      "id": 800,
      "name": "product name 1"
    }
]
}'
```

I am trying to build the Object the following way, but it doesn't work:

```
var APIPayloadObject = {update:[]};

//starting loop
for ( i = 0; i < lastrow; i++){
   var product = [];
   product.push({
      id: loopRange[i][0],
      name: loopRange[i][1]
   })

   //???????

}
Logger.log(JSON.stringify(APIPayloadObject));
```

**At question marks I don't know how to push product array into the object**

Comment: Why don't you just use the `APIPayloadObject.update.push()` instead of reinitializing the `product` Array at each loop stage, since `update ` property already contains an instance of `Array` as value?

Comment: Simply because I am just a hobby developer and I have no experience in this. :) I thought it should be really simple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Sample 1**

As mentioned in my comment, the first solution is to access the `update` property and invoke `push()` on it since you already defined `update` to contain an `Array` instance:

```
//starting loop
for ( i = 0; i < lastrow; i++){
   APIPayloadObject.update.push({
      id:   loopRange[i][0],
      name: loopRange[i][1]
   })
}
```

**Sample 2**

You can take it one step further and directly write your objects to `update` Array at the `i` index, since you start from 0:

```
//starting loop
for ( i = 0; i < lastrow; i++){
   APIPayloadObject.update[i] = {
      id:   loopRange[i][0],
      name: loopRange[i][1]
   };
}
```

Comment: Your sample led me to the solution. When I simply declared the Object this way: 
`var APIPayloadObject = {};` I always got _TypeError:  undefined "push" method can not be called_. I added one more line: `APIPayloadObject.update = [];` and now it works as I expected. Thank you.

Comment: NP, glad it pointed you in the right direction! As for the `TypeError` - this was simply because `push()` is a method of `Array` and isn't present in the built-in it inherits from (`Object`) -> constructor `{}` returns an instance of `Object` and `[]` an instance of `Array`

Comment: one more thing: could you please write to me how to set field name if that is also stored in a variable? I am going to create a general function which can be called regardless of which field is being changed. This doesn't work: `APIPayloadObject.update.push({[changedField]: updateValue})`

Comment: Sure - if you are used to ES6 calculated properties, forget about using them inside the `{}` constructor (apps script is based on an earlier version) - write your object into a variable, then add calculated prop via bracket notation like this: `obj[varProp] = value` and you should be good to go.

Comment: sorry for tiring you. Basically it works, but I can't figure out how to put properties into the object if there should be an array in the object first. Please see the object example at the very begging of this thread. First I create an array in the object `APIPayloadObject.update = [];` and then I should push propertien into that. thanks.

Comment: No worries, but I am not sure I understand you - your JSON schema suggests that you need an *object* that has one property by name *update* with value - an instance of `Array`, which is then referenced by property name to push values into it. After you create an array with `update = []` to push to it you just reference the property, thus the answer - `APIPayloadObject.update.push()`

Comment: This is where we started from I think. :) The only think what I don't know how to push property into that with dynamic (stored in variable) name.

Comment: I see - to avoid confusion, properties are usually "set") As I mentioned, use bracket notation, first initiate the array and write it to value: `APIPayloadObject[yourVariableRef] = []`, then push values into array `APIPayloadObject[yourVariableRef].push( yourValue )`

Answer (score 1):

This is a great use case for [Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

```js
// @param {sheetValues[][]} loopRange
function getPayload(loopRange) {
  return JSON.stringify({
    update: loopRange.map(function (row) {
      return {id: row[0], name: row[1]};
    })
  });
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I haven't checked your code because the first suggestion led me to the solution. ;)